# Pode instalar certificado ssl em 2 ou mais servidores?

Tags: php, iis, microsoft-azure, ssl

Bom dia, possuo dois servidores web sendo um linux hospedado na locaweb, o qual hospeda o site principal da empresa, e o outro windows hospedado no azure, este ultimo sendo específico para aplicações asp.net.

Tenho um certificado wildcard, o qual abrange tanto o domínio principal quanto os subdomínios, conseguiria aplicar o mesmo certificado ssl em ambos os servidores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondendo a esta dúvida, sim é possível sim instalar um mesmo certificado em múltiplos servidores, neste caso eu poderia instalar o certificado no servidor linux onde está o hospedado o site principal e então gerar a solicitação de certificado no servidor azure, entrar em contato com a emissora do certificado e solicitar a reemissão do mesmo para a instalação num segundo servidor.

A reemissão não invalida o primeiro certificado, o que me permite utilizar o mesmo certificado em múltiplos servidores, desde que os mesmos respeitem a regra *.dominio.com.br..

Acredito que esta regra deve variar de emissora para emissora, no meu caso a comodobr não cobra a reemissão do certificado.

Answer (score 1):

É possivel dependendo de como o certificado foi gerado, se ele foi gerado especificamente para um ip ou para um dominio, é só garantir isso. No caso se voce possui um específico para ip e servidores diferentes mas com o ip igual e em portas diferentes é possivel utilizar sem problemas.